# why processor cache stuck at 8Mb?

Tags: caching, intel, processor

Eight years ago I can buy [Core 2 Duo processor with 6Mb cache](http://ark.intel.com/products/42599/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-P9700-6M-Cache-2_80-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB).

Today we can buy something like [i7 with 8Mb cache](http://ark.intel.com/products/88195/Intel-Core-i7-6700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz)

Why cache growing up so slow? It's to hard to implement, or maybe there is no reason to do, or maybe it's different cache?

Comment: Big many-core Intel CPUs (Xeon) have 1.5 or 2MiB of shared L3 per core, connected by the same ring bus that the cores use to communicate with each other at all.  The biggest of these CPUs have over 30MiB of L3.  Outside of servers, Broadwell introduced an eDRAM 128MiB L4 cache in some models.  It makes a big difference to the integrated GPU, but also to compression algorithms and other memory-intensive CPU work with a working-set between 8MiB and 128MiB.  Skylake rearranged the eDRAM to be a memory-side cache (that can even cache DMA), but it isn't available in any desktop Skylake chips :((((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky question indeed. The 8 MB you are talking about, is the amount of L3 cache found in some high level CPUs like i7 and some xeons.

The optimal amount of cache is obtained by a calculus between the maximum amount of RAM for the system, the number of physical cores and the CPU cycles.
For instance [this Xeon CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/84688/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E7-8893-v3-45M-Cache-3_20-GHz) got 45 MB of cache but can handle 8 threads and 1.5TB of memory..

The cache of the CPU is made of multiple types L1, L2, L3 and L4 (Also known as [eDram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDRAM), is a high bandwidth DRAM, first seen in video game consoles (like XBOX 360 and PlayStation 2) and dedicated to the internal GPU. The commercial name for the Intel Chips with internal GPU + eDRAM is Iris PRO. The [Haswell microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture)) was the first Intel microprocessor to propose this graphical enhanced design. This L4 is used as a [Victim Cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Victim_cache) for the L3 cache).

Look the complete specifications of one of the recent [i7 cpu from intel](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7-4790.html) to see an example of the kind of caches you can find internally.
But it's **not only the amount** of cache that matters **but the nature of it**.  The latest CPUs have level 3 (L3), 8 ways memory type (to be compared with 2 or 4 ways in the past) providing synchronous access to the 8 virtual cores. 
The closer the cache is to the cpu, the faster he is. 
The L1 cache (the faster and the more expensive) is used per physical core, L2 more or less for the threads and the L3 for DMA channel (buffered) communication with the main memory.

The more cache you have the less **'cache hit misses'** you get. The number of misses (errors) is related to the CPU cycles (speed in Mhz) and the amount of cache.

According to the statistics, above a specific limit increasing the amount of cache provides a little or no performance improvement. **So the cost of the CPU increases for a very small improvement**. 
The amount of cache must respect a ratio between performance improvement and cost.
The same reason explains why you can find more ram on high end cpus.

The speed of the ram is also improving over the time, so the amount of cache is less critical for CPU performance has it was in the past.

For a full article on the subject I recommend [this very good page](https://lwn.net/Articles/252125/).